# VBA Code Sum the price of each customer items

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop, sum, iteration

I was trying to sum the items price to find the difference between total price and final sum price using VBA code the difference should need paste in adjustable column but here the output gives all the sum values through iteration

here is my code:

```
Const start_row = 2
Const tot_price = 3
Const cus_id_num = 1
Sub refresh()
    Dim cus_id      As String
    Dim fee_item    As String
    Dim temp        As Variant
    
    i = start_row
    j = 1
    cus_id = Me.Cells(i, 1).Value
    While Me.Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
        If Me.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "0" Then
            If cus_id <> Me.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                cus_id = Me.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
            Debug.Print cus_id
            ''Debug.Print cus_id
            If cus_id <> "" Then
                If Me.Cells(i, tot_price).Value <> "" Then
                    base_fee = Me.Cells(i, tot_price).Value
                End If
                Debug.Print base_fee
                temp = 0
            Else
                If Me.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
                    fee_item = Round(Me.Cells(i, tot_price).Value, 0)
                    temp = fee_item + temp
                End If
                Debug.Print temp
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

data for the problem:

```
Customer_id_number||Items            ||      Total Price || Adjustable
70                ||  groceries      ||         1578.00  ||  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Detergent Powder             719.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Detergent Soap               58.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Floor cleaner liquid         396.00
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Tooth Paste                  58.14
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Tooth Brush                  27.51
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Shampoo                      219.77
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Perfume                      100.00
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
40                 vegetable and fruits         1370.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Tomatoes                     88.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Onions                       38.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Sweet Potatoes               93.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Oranges                      809.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Mangoes                      282.03
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Spinach                      59.90
```

Image:
[data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyVc1.png)

Output:
70
1578

719

777

1173

1231

1259

1479

1579

40
1370

88

126

219

1028

1310

1370

I need final sum output through each iteration can someone help me here

Thankyou so much in advance!

Comment: I haven't fully understood your requirement nor what you code does or is missing. Anyhow, have you thought about using a pivot table for that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read [mcve] and give a proper sample of input data and desired output. Screenshots might help too. Explain on that sample data what exactly you try to do. Have you considered using formulas like `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`? • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: When you say "customer items" do you mean per each "customer_ID_Number\items"?

Comment: I am sorry i have edited my question can you please help with this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are the values sorted as you show them in the code?

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes the values are sorted as it is shown in the output but i don't need each iteration output as shown it should be the one final output of sumof items to each customer and the difference amount of total price and sum of items to be pasted in adjustable column

Comment: And the empty cells bellow an ID are exactly as you show them?

Comment: @FaneDuru,Yes it is exactly how it is above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to add the totals for every customer, and at the end, you would also like to have a grand total.

Why are you using VBA for this? The `Subtotals` feature is a basic feature in Excel, as explained in [this official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a), let me show you an example:

Data:

```
CustID    Price
    70     1578
    70     719
    70     777
    70     1173
    70     1231
    70     1259
    70     1479
    70     1579
    40     1370
    40     88
    40     126
    40     219
    40     1028
    40     1310
    40     1370
```

Subtotals usage:

[image]

The results either shows all data with subtotals per customer and grand total, or just subtotals and grand total, or just the grand total (click on the numbers <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> in the left margin).

The starting of this "subtotals" feature can be recorded in a macro, you'll get something like:

```
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply! 
This sheet is tool generated it requires VBA code to perform these calculations when user download the sheet after enable content difference amount to  be pasted in adjustable column

Comment: ... you can record the `Subtotals` feature in a macro and replay it at every update of the file.

Comment: @vinay: I edited my answer accordingly, however I don't understand all parameters in the VBA command.

Comment: Thank you @Dominique for your swift reply, subtotals is useful here but i am looking for VBA code that should iterate the loop between each customer sum of items and should check the difference amount between total price value  and sum of items in data given above and difference amount should pasted in adjustable

Comment: No problem. Let me show you another feature of Excel (I suppose that "Customer_ID_Number" is column A?): select the whole column A, press "Ctrl+G" and Goto Blanks. Then, in the formula bar, you type `=A2` (I guess you start at row 2?) and then, press "Ctrl+ENTER" (NOT just "ENTER") and all customer IDs get filled in with the value just above (which makes other features, like filtering, very easy).

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. Not tested, but it should work, if I correctly understood the question:

```
Sub testSummaryzePerCustID()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value    'Place the range in an array for faster iteration
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'reDim the final array to have the same number of rows as arr
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)       'iterate between the array elements
        If arr(i, 1) = "" Then    'for cases of nullString in first column:
            If k = 1 Then         'first time it uses the value in the third column
                arrFin(i, 1) = arr(i, 3): k = k + 1
            Else
               arrFin(i, 1) = arrFin(i - 1, 1) + arr(i, 3) 'then it adds the values in the third column to the previous arrFin value
            End If
        Else
            arrFin(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) & " " & arr(i, 3): k = 1 'concatenate ID with value of the third column
        End If
   Next i
   'drop the final array content at once:
   sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

If you need to round the returned sums to not show decimals (as you show us in your question), I can adapt the code to do it. Now, it only adds them and shows all resulted decimals.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru, but it is giving an error - subscript out of range , i have added picture above for clear table data

Comment: I am driving now...

Comment: I anyhow forgot to increment i by k... I will adapt it whwn I will be at home.

Comment: Please let me know once tested it successfully.

Comment: @Virat OK. I am at home now. I will adapt the code in 5 - 6 minutes. I need to build a testing sheet...

Comment: @Virat Please, check the updated code. I tried commenting it, in order to be easily understood...

Comment: @Virat Didn't you find some time to test the updated code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, i am sorry, couldn't find time to check the code over last weekend now i tested it and it is working as expected thank you

Comment: @Vira Glad I (finally) could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else will know that the code works as it should... :)